# Rails/Passenger sub URI error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I am attempting to deploy a Rails 3.0.0 application to a sub URI using passenger 2.2.15.

I believe I've made the correct `RailsBaseURI` changes to my http.conf , have symlinked the sub URI to the public directory of my app and added the following line of code to `environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/sub_uri"
```

I've done this several times pre-rails3.0.0. That said, the app won't launch.  It fails with the following Passenger error:

```
Error Message: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Exception class: ArgumentError

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb 54 in `relative_url_root='
```

Is there an incompatibility between passenger 2.2.15 and rails 3.0.0 that affects sub URI's?

Any help sorting out this error is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error saying you are giving it 1 argument instead of the expected 0 makes me think that they aren't letting you set the relative_url_root anymore.

Edit: After investigation, it seems the setter is depreciated and now favored as an environment variable: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setter is depreciated, it's nowhere to be found in `actionpack/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb`.

As seen here (`actionpack/lib/action_controller/depreciated/base.rb`):

```
module ActionController
  class Base
    # Deprecated methods. Wrap them in a module so they can be overwritten by plugins
    # (like the verify method.)
    module DeprecatedBehavior #:nodoc:
      def relative_url_root
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "ActionController::Base.relative_url_root is ineffective. " <<
          "Please stop using it.", caller
      end

      def relative_url_root=
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "ActionController::Base.relative_url_root= is ineffective. " <<
          "Please stop using it.", caller
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In `actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb` you can see it's setter is an `ENV` variable:

```
self.config.relative_url_root = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
```

So you need to set the ENV variable: `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT="/sub_uri"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything with the final rails3 release.

Comment: Worked for me.  Using Rails 3.0.0 and Passenger 3.0.0.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To set the environment variable add:

```
SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT /sub_uri
```

To the `VirtualHost` section (or similar) of your apache config then make sure it's being read by restarting apache and passenger.

```
cd <your_rails_project>
sudo apache2ctl graceful
touch tmp/restart
```